# Dynamic height for UICollectionView inside StackView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I am trying to figure out how to set AutoLayout constraints for a UICollectionView inside of a UIStackView (or without the StackView) and feel confused. The other answers on StackOverflow that I have found do not seem to directly apply.

Here is what I have:

```
-----------------------------------
|  -----------------------------  |
|  |    UICollectionView # 1    | | (Sticky header for whole view)
|  -----------------------------  |
|  -----------------------------  |
|  |    UICollectionView # 2    | | (Table/grid with sections)
|  -----------------------------  |
|  -----------------------------  |
|  |    Button                  | |
|  -----------------------------  |
|  -----------------------------  |
|  |    UICollectionView # 3    | | (Sticky footer)
|  -----------------------------  |
```

I am aware that there are now stick section headers for collection views, but collection #2 has it's own sections, so these are sticky headers for the whole view, which doesn't exist.

I can set constraints for views #1, #3, and the button, but #2's height is unknown. How do I set it so that view can dynamically change height, BUT view #3 is always visible.

I.e. View #2 will start to scroll if it becomes too long, and view #3 will stay visible.

Comment: is your colletionview horizontal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want a self-sizing collection view, you have to create an `NSLayoutConstraint` for the collection view's height:

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then, in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, update the height constraint and layout the view:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

When you reload your collection view, make sure to call `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
collectionView.reloadData()
viewDidLayoutSubviews()
```

Comment: Would I need to reset that constant and do `view.layoutIfNeeded()` anytime a new item is added/deleted then?

Comment: No. `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called automatically when you do `collectionView.reloadData()`. If not, just call `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` right after you update your collection view.

Comment: Okay, I did a preliminary test and this seemed to work just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect Answer! Thanks